# How is account abstraction sustainable and safe?

Tags: account-abstraction

When a DApp, like [Dmail](https://dmail.ai/) for example, covers gas for its users using account abstraction, can't it be very expensive to operate?

Also, how is the DApp safe from users spamming it with requests causing fund bankruptcy and as a result denial-of-service?

Answer (score 0):

Account abstraction can be sustainable and safe by implementing measures such as user authentication, rate limiting, and transaction verification.
Additionally, utilizing smart contract logic to manage and allocate gas costs can help control expenses for the DApp.

To prevent spamming and denial-of-service attacks, implementing user quotas, request validation, and automated monitoring for unusual activity can safeguard the DApp's resources.
Regular security audits and updates to address potential vulnerabilities are also essential for maintaining the DApp's safety and stability.